# Export php array to csv rows instead of columns

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fputcsv

Is there a way to put a php array in a csv file entering every item of the array as a new row? This is what I have:

```
$list = array (
        array('names'),
        array('bob,bill,john,sally'));

    $fp = fopen('files.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

My csv looks like this:

```
names
bob,bill,john,sally
```

However this is what I'm looking for:

```
names
bob
bill
john
sally
```

Comment: What you're describing isn't csv (comma separated values). You should just iterate over the arrays, add the names to a string (with newlines) and then save that string to the file (so you don't save to the file 100 times)

Comment: @JimL ok makes a lot of sense. I'm doing some things with the file in Powershell which I'm new to and i'm able to easily import a csv with it in my desired format. Should be pretty easy to just save each item to a new line.

Comment: Is that a typo in your `$list` declaration or are you missing a `)`? Also sounds like you were able to solve the problem?

Comment: @Rizier123 that was a typo thanks. Yes was able to solve I replaced my `fputcsv($fp, $fields);` with `fwrite($fp, $fields.PHP_EOL);`

Comment: @RyanLitwiller So you can self-answer your question if you want and mark it as solved by accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a matter of using `fwrite()` instead of `fputcsv()`

```
$list = array (
        array('names'),
        array('bob,bill,john,sally'));

    $fp = fopen('files.csv', 'w');

    foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fwrite($fp, $fields.PHP_EOL);
    }

    fclose($fp);
```